# R Get percentage difference from previous row

Tags: r, diff, lag

I have a dataset with 4 columns, 1st col is date, the other 3 are numeric. I am trying to get the % diff from previous row for those 3 numeric columns. I know there already have some posts about this kind of questions `df %>% mutate_each(funs(. - lag(.))) %>% na.omit()`, but most of them can not take care about the date, since I want the date to be unchange, and need % different.

here is the dataset

```
date=c('2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01')
a=c(1,3,2)
b=c(89,56,47)
c=c(1872,7222,2930)
x=data.frame(date,a,b,c)
```

I wish to have the final dataset like this

```
x=data.frame(date,a,b,c)
a=c(NA, 2, -0.333)
b=c(NA, -0.371, -0.161)
c=c(NA,2.857, -0.594)
x=data.frame(date,a,b,c)
```

which means for col A, 2=3/1-1, -0.333=2/3-1
for col B, -0.371=56/89-1 etc

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using package `data.table`:

```
x = as.data.table(x)
cols = c("a", "b", "c")
x[,(paste0(cols, "_pctChange")) := lapply(.SD, function(col){ 
      (col-shift(col,1,type = "lag"))/shift(col,1,type = "lag")
  }), .SDcols=cols]
```

Answer (score 0):

`quantmod` package has a very useful function for exactly this called `Delt()`.

All you would need to do is the following:

```
x[-1] <- sapply(x[-1], Delt)
```

I'm not sure how familiar you are with sapply, but if you wanted to access `Delt()`'s parameters to tweak your calculation, you could try something like:

```
x[-1] <- sapply(x[-1], function(x) { Delt(x, k=2) })
```